# Agora exception in release mode Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, agora.io

I am using Agora rtc in my flutter app for live streaming it works fine in debug mode
but in release I got this exception and live dose not start

log Exception when trying to open Live Stream :

```
E/flutter (22524): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Incomplete hierarchy for class RtcEngineManager, unresolved classes [io.agora.rtc.base.IRtcEngine$RtcEngineInterface], null, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incomplete hierarchy for class RtcEngineManager, unresolved classes [io.agora.rtc.base.IRtcEngine$RtcEngineInterface]
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.components.RuntimeErrorReporter.reportIncompleteHierarchy(Unknown Source:41)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassTypeConstructor.computeSupertypes(Unknown Source:211)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.AbstractTypeConstructor$supertypes$1.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.AbstractTypeConstructor$supertypes$1.invoke(Unknown Source:0)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(Unknown Source:86)    
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(Unknown Source:0)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.AbstractTypeConstructor.getSupertypes(Unknown Source:2)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope.getNonDeclaredVariableNames(Unknown Source:8)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$variableNamesLazy$2.invoke(Unknown Source:12)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$variableNamesLazy$2.invoke(Unknown Source:0)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(Unknown Source:86)    
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(Unknown Source:0)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.StorageKt.getValue(Unknown Source:10)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope.getVariableNamesLazy(Unknown Source:7)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope.getVariableNames(Unknown Source:0)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope.addFunctionsAndProperties(Unknown Source:14)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope.computeDescriptors(Unknown Source:36)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope$allDescriptors$1.invoke(Unknown Source:12)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope$allDescriptors$1.invoke(Unknown Source:0)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(Unknown Source:86)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(Unknown Source:0)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope.getContributedDescriptors(Unknown Source:12)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.scopes.ResolutionScope$DefaultImpls.getContributedDescriptors$default(Unknown Source:18)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KDeclarationContainerImpl.getMembers(Unknown Source:17)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$declaredNonStaticMembers$2.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$declaredNonStaticMembers$2.invoke(Unknown Source:0)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(Unknown Source:17)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(Unknown Source:0)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data.getDeclaredNonStaticMembers(Unknown Source:8)
E/flutter (22524):      at kotlin.reflect.full.KClasses.getDe
E/flutter (22524): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Please init RtcEngine first!, 
null, java.lang.RuntimeException: Please init RtcEngine first!
E/flutter (22524):      at io.agora.rtc.base.RtcSurfaceView.<init>(Unknown Source:36)
```

Comment: So, the log is showing that you didn't init the rtcEngine properly. 
```java.lang.RuntimeException: Please init RtcEngine first!```

Can you please include some code???

Comment: this is init method  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // initialize agora sdk
   initialize();
  }

Comment: Future<void> initialize() async {
   await _initAgoraRtcEngine();
    _addAgoraEventHandlers();
    await _engine.enableWebSdkInteroperability(true);
    VideoEncoderConfiguration configuration = VideoEncoderConfiguration();
    configuration.dimensions = VideoDimensions(1920, 1080);
    _engine.setParameters("{\"rtc.log_filter\": 65535}");
    await _engine.setVideoEncoderConfiguration(configuration);
    await _engine.joinChannel(Auth.AgoraToken, widget.channelName, null, 0);}

Comment: Future<void> _initAgoraRtcEngine() async {
    _engine = await RtcEngine.create(Auth.AgoraAppID);
    await _engine.enableVideo();
    await _engine.setChannelProfile(ChannelProfile.LiveBroadcasting);
    await _engine.setClientRole(widget.role);
  }

Comment: Hey @KhAleD, it seems like you forgot to call the initialize() function inside your initState(). Right now your initState is not initializing anything. You can have a look at this sample code given over here to get started with a live streaming application using Agora's Flutter SDK : https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Flutter-Quickstart

Comment: try setting `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources` to false in `app/build.gradle` file.